# how to call multiple function url in single azure function app using proxies

Tags: c#

i have created multiple functions in single function app where all the functions were created as each proxies. how to write the code for calling multiple functions as proxies in single other function(main). i can call those functions in the browser by changing manual but it should be done automatically. how to do that.

Comment: Can you provide us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: i created one single function app..in that i created many functions with different name.and i also created proxies for each function in the same function app. now i have to call that those multiple proxies in single function. how to write code in function for calling multiple proxies in single function.